# Nested hash manipulation

Tags: ruby

I would appreciate if someone can help me figure out why my code is not passing. 
I have given arguments here.

cart item:

```
{
  "AVOCADO" => {:price => 3.0, :clearance => true, :count => 3},
  "KALE"    => {:price => 3.0, :clearance => false, :count => 1}
}
```

coupons:

```
{:item => "AVOCADO", :num => 2, :cost => 5.0}
```

It requires me to return this:

```
    {
  "AVOCADO" => {:price => 3.0, :clearance => true, :count => 1},
  "KALE"    => {:price => 3.0, :clearance => false, :count => 1},
  "AVOCADO W/COUPON" => {:price => 5.0, :clearance => true, :count => 1},
    }
```

Here's my code:

```
def apply_coupons(cart:[], coupons:[])

  app_coupon = {}
  cart.each do |items|
    items.each do |item_name, value|
      app_coupon[item_name] = value
      coupons.each do |coupon|
        if coupon[:item] == item_name
           app_coupon["#{coupon[:item]} W/COUPON"] = {:price => coupon[:cost], :clearance => value[:clearance], :count => value[:count] / coupon[:num] }
           app_coupon[item_name][:count] -= coupon[:num]
        end
      end
    end
  end
  app_coupon
 end
```

Comment: It's not clear why your coupon has `num: 2` and yet you're only discounting one with a coupon. You're also declaring keyword arguments with array defaults when you're actually expecting a hash.

Comment: yes, my arguments are hashes inside the cart & coupons array.

Comment: You might want to declare the method as `cart:{}, coupons:{}` if that's the case. It is odd you're using Ruby 2.3 keyword-arugments but Ruby 1.8 hash notation. For consistency: `price: 3.0, clearance: true, ...`

Comment: Maybe you can better explain your logic here when it comes to computing how many get the coupon, plus what the function of the `%=` part is. It's not clear what the problem is, or how it could be fixed.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the advice . However, do you notice anything that is causing it not to pass? Let me paste the link to the challenge. I really appreciate your help and time. 
https://learn.co/tracks/web-development-fundamentals/intro-to-ruby/bonus-advanced-hashes/green-grocer

Comment: What do you mean "not pass"? Clearly this method returns *something*.

Comment: sorry about that, I'm using rspec to test it and it's not passing on my end. My only question is, do you think my code is correct in returning the expected value? I'm new to coding that's why I need guidance from others XD

Comment: When in doubt, experiment with `irb` to see what results you're getting. I'm not sure what you're getting here  that's mistaken. Tests like `rspec` help in identifying narrowing down problems, but they can't solve them without some intervention on your part.

Comment: This question would benefit from including an example of the actual, erroneous output.

Answer (score 0):

One possible problem..

coupons:

```
{:item => "AVOCADO", :num => 2, :cost => 5.0}
```

... this is just a single hash, but in your code you're doing...

```
coupons.each do |coupon|
```

... so you're expecting an array.  You should make coupons:

```
[{:item => "AVOCADO", :num => 2, :cost => 5.0}]
```

Comment: Actually it looks like this when i'm trying it in irb. 
`apply_coupons(cart: [{
  "AVOCADO" => {:price => 3.0, :clearance => true, :count => 3},
  "KALE"    => {:price => 3.0, :clearance => false, :count => 1}
}], coupons: [{:item => "AVOCADO", :num => 2, :cost => 5.0}])`

Comment: So I tried it, it works fine! I got the result... `{"AVOCADO"=>{:price=>3.0, :clearance=>true, :count=>1}, "AVOCADO W/COUPON"=>{:price=>5.0, :clearance=>true, :count=>1}, "KALE"=>{:price=>3.0, :clearance=>false, :count=>1}}
`

Comment: So the problem is your test (rspec).  Can you post your rspec code and explain what error you're seeing in your tests?